# c programming: answer always equates to 0

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    double Radius, Circumference, Area, Pi = 3.1416;
    
    printf("Value of Radius:");
    scanf("%lf",Radius);
    
    Area = Pi * Radius * Radius;
    Circumference = 2 * Pi * Radius;
    
    printf("The area of the circle is %lf", Area);
    printf("\nThe circumference of the circle is %lf", Circumference);
    
    return 0; 
}
```

I want to be able to get both circumference and area by just plugging in the radius.

Comment: OT: put `\n` at the _end_ of output strings... Outputting two lines, but only one `\n` in the code...

Comment: ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. It would have found the problem. With `gcc`, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Tip: `int main()` should be `int main( void )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `scanf` function needs a pointer.

```
scanf("%lf", &Radius);
```

You should have received a warning (enable warnings!) on compiling this:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:14: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%lf",Radius);
            ~~^
```

You should also check the return value of `scanf` to ensure it actually read the correct number of values.